# Mercurial website VC over HTTP or FTP - no SSH

Tags: mercurial

I would like to have a mercurial repository on my website so that I can push/pull as I make updates to it, but I do not have SSH access, only HTTP or FTP.

Can this be done?

I suspect no, since I would not be able to run `hg` on the server, so I would only be able to clone it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, this can definitely be done.  You don't need ssh access to install mercurial or to access it.  You compile it on your own system and then FTP up the resulting file.  The only real requirement is that the website to which you upload it allow CGI applications to run.  Without that you're limited to the static-http repositories, which don't support pushing.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct.  If you can't install software, you could use the [static-http](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/StaticHTTP) option, but it only supports cloning/pulling.  See the [comparison](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories) of publishing mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup hgweb to [allow pushes](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStep#Allow_pushing_to_the_repository).

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using only FTP to update my site, but I keep all the files in a local Mercurial repo (you could use a repository on [bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org/) - they have a free plan that includes 1 private repo and 1 GB of available space). When you need to add/update something, apply the 
changes locally, update the Mercurial repo, and then use FTP to update the website.